unable to read data from stdout of subprocess, involves Pi High Quality Camera for YOLO Object Detection on Raspberry Pi 4
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and a Pi High Quality Camera. I want to process video from the camera and run object detection using the YOLO model (YOLOv8 in this case). However, I encounter some issues when reading video frames in YUV format and converting them to RGB for YOLO processing. Below is my code:
import cv2
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import os
from ultralytics import YOLO

os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "xcb"

process = subprocess.Popen(
   ['libcamera-vid', '--codec', 'yuv420', '--width', '640', '--height', '480', '--framerate', 
   '15', '-o', '-'],
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
   bufsize=10**8
 )

 frame_size = int(640 * 480 * 1.5)

 model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")  # Use yolov8n.pt or another model of your choice

 try:
    while True:
      raw = process.stdout.read(4096)
      if not raw:
        print("Unable to read data")
        break

      if len(raw) < frame_size:
        print(f"Incomplete data. Expected size: {frame_size}, Received size: {len(raw)}")
        continue  # Skip this frame

      try:
        yuv = np.frombuffer(raw, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((int(480 * 1.5), 640))
      except ValueError as ve:
        print(f"Error reshaping YUV data: {ve}")
        continue  # Skip this frame

      frame = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420)

      results = model(frame)

      for result in results:
        if result.boxes is not None:
            for box in result.boxes:
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box.xyxy[0]  # Bounding box coordinates
                confidence = box.conf[0]  # Confidence level
                class_id = int(box.cls[0])  # Class ID
                class_name = result.names[class_id]  # Class name
                print(f"Detection: {class_name} (Confidence: {confidence:.2f}) at [{x1:.2f}, 
                {y1:.2f}, {x2:.2f}, {y2:.2f}]")
 except Exception as e:
print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    process.terminate()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Issue:
1.I’m not able to correctly handle the raw YUV data from libcamera-vid. Sometimes the data
seems incomplete or cannot be reshaped into the correct format for conversion.
2.I’m unsure if I’m correctly converting the YUV420 format to RGB using cv2.COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420.
3.The YOLO model runs, but I’m not sure if the input frames are being processed correctly, as
detection results seem inaccurate.

result is "Unable to read data"

unable to read? then you do not have an issue converting that data, which you couldn't read in the first place.

[mre] required. that's not a MRE. rewrite it so the issue raises an exception (e.g. with an assertion), then present the traceback. remove all/most of the code that comes after the exception
